# Recursive regex doesn’t work

Tags: php, regex

The string I work on looks like that:

```
abc {def ghi {jkl mno} pqr stv} xy z
```

And I need to put what figure parentheses are containing in tags, so it should looks like this

```
abc <tag>def ghi <tag>jkl mno</tag> pqr stv</tag> xy z
```

I’ve tried

```
'#(?<!\pL)\{  ( ([^{}]+) | (?R) )*  \}(?!\pL)#xu'
```

but what I get is just `<tag>xy z</tag>`. Help please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about two steps:

`s!{!<tag>!g;`
`s!}!</tag>!g;`

(perl format; translate to your format as appropriate)

or maybe this:

`1 while s!{([^{}]*)}!<tag>$1</tag>!g;`

Comment: Already thought about it. It is simple but may cause breaking of markup if matched parenthesis will not be found.

Comment: You can just repeatedly call the search/replace.  (answer updated)

Answer (score 5):

Nested structures are by definition too complicated for regular expressions (yes, PCRE supports recursion, but that does not help for this replacement-problem). There are two possible options for you (using regular expressions anyway). Firstly, you could simply replace opening brackets by opening tags and the same for closing tags. This, however, will convert unmatched brackets as well:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\{/', '<tag>', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/\}/', '</tag>', $str);
```

Another option is to only replace matching `{` and `}`, but then you have to do it repeatedly, because one call to `preg_replace` cannot replace multiple nested levels:

```
do
{
    $str = preg_replace('/\{([^{]*?)\}/', '<tag>$1</tag>', $str, -1, $count);
}
while ($count > 0)
```

**EDIT:** While PCRE supports recursion with `(?R)` this will most likely not help with a replacement. The reason is that, if a capturing group is repeated, its reference will only contain the last capturing (i.e. when matching `/(a|b)+/` in `aaaab`, `$1` will contain `b`). I suppose that this is the same for recursion. That is why you can only replace the innermost match because it's the last match of the capturing group within the recursion. Likewise, you could not try to capture `{` and `}` with recursion and replace these, because they might also be matched an arbitrary number of times and only the last match will be replaced.

Just matching a correct nested syntax and then replacing the innermost or outermost matching brackets will not help either (with one `preg_replace` call), because multiple matches will never overlap (so if 3 nested brackets have been found, the inner 2 brackets themselves will be disregarded for further matches).

Comment: This is  what `(?R)` stands for.

Comment: That definition only works if your expression are "regular expressions" in the mathematical sense. PCRE, which are what PHP uses, aren't regular by any stretch of the imagination: you can (as the asker did) use `(?R)` to make the expression *recursive*, for example! Now, whether this is a good idea is another question, but it shouldn't be actually impossible.

Comment: You are right, that PCRE supports `(?R)` but I cannot seem to find any (recommended) examples using it for `preg_replace`. It usually seems to be used for `preg_match` only.

Comment: I didn’t knew that. Thank you.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis (and @OP of course) I have added an explanation why the recursion feature cannot really work with `preg_replace` in this case.